# How to optimize RAM usage for airdrop

Tags: airdrops

I want to conduct airdrop for all eos holders. Taking into consideration that the airdrop for one account will use around 0,2 KiB I have to shell out around 250K KiB of RAM without CPU and Net  which is more than 160K USD. Can I reduce this amount without reducing the amount of accounts that I'm going to use in airdrop? In other words if there any way to optimize airdrop?

Thanks

Comment: You can contact AirdropsDac. Last I heard they drop for around $5k

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not buy the RAM yourself, but instead let users buy it. See for example the poorman token:

https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/new-airdrop-poor-tokens-announced-let-s-make-eos-better

Here users have to claim their airdrop in order to use it, and when claiming they pay for the very small amount of RAM that is used to add their balance to the table.

Comment: Thanks! As far as I see sometimes it's called airgrab. This is one of the option, but it has a disadvantage it needs additional promotion and outlays.

Comment: Btw, what's is a 'skyhook'? Does anyone has clear explanation for that method?